# How to calculate $(I - xy^T)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

> Let $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ and suppose that $x^T y \neq 1$, compute $(I - xy^T)^{-1}$.

Really don't know how to work it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam , do the calculation when $x=[a,b]^T,y=[c,d]^T,ac+bd\not =0$. It's the minimum you need to do.

Comment: Use [Sherman–Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman–Morrison_formula).

Answer (score 4):

When I see something like $(1-z)^{-1}$ I think of $1+z+z^2+\ldots\ \ $  Let's try that here without worrying about niceties like convergence of the sum.  Note that $(xy^T)^n=x(y^Tx)^{n-1}y^T$ so we try 
$$(1-xy^T)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (xy^T)^i=1+x\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty(y^Tx)^i\right)y^T=1+\frac 1{1-y^Tx}xy^T$$
If you multiply this by $1-xy^T$ you get $1$ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

According to Cayley Hamilton, $(I-xy^T)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $xy^T$, that is $a_0I+a_1xy^T+\cdots+a_{n-1}(xy^T)^{n-1}$. Since $(xy^T)^2=(y^Tx)(xy^T)$, we deduce that $(I-xy^T)^{-1}$ is in the form $aI+bxy^T$.

From $(aI+bxy^T)(I-xy^T)=I$, we deduce, by identification, that $a=1,b=1/(1-y^Tx)$.